# How do I list all servers in a discord.js v12 bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command so when you go ;listservers it brings a list of current servers the bot is in but my code is sending servers one at a time making it really slow is there anyway I could fix this? this is my current code

```
    message.channel.send(`Found ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers\nServer List:`)
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        message.channel.send(`${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all servers in one message you can just use one line of code:

```
message.channel.send(client.guilds.cache.map(m => `${m.name} | ${m.id}`).join("\n"))
```